# Use BIM360 Model Coordination transform position in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

When using Model Coordination in BIM360, we can reposition a model with the "transform" function.

Is it possible to acces this transform value when loading models in the Forge viewer?
We are using the "AggregatedView" methods to load models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data is stored in the view of the specific model set version. you will need to use Model Coordination API to get it.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/mc-modelset-service-v3-get-model-set-view-version-GET/
This is a snapshot of my test. alignment tells data of transformation

It looks the API document above has not updated with the related information. I am reporting this to engineer team.

If you have not been familiar with  Model Coordination API. The tutorial and Postman collection might help:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/model-coordination/
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/postman-collections-model-coordination-api

[image]